# ClamTK on latest Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, clamtk

I recently installed ClamTK from the Lubuntu software repository to my Lenovo T61 laptop. It worked fine once or twice then would not even load the interface. As ClamTK works faultlessly on my PC with Ubuntu 16.10 I was annoyed so did a new install of Lubuntu (Ubuntu 16.10) on the laptop. This time it worked fine once after which it will not load the interface.

I previously ran the full Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop and encountered no problem with ClamTK. So feel it's probably a Lubuntu conflict.

Would appreciate some help. Incidentally, I used Clam for years on another distro - PCLinuxOS, both the full (on PC) and the XFCE version (on laptop) and never had any problem.

Comment: Have you tried running `clamtk` or `clamtk-gnome` from the command promt to check the output? Also, maybe try with sudo? `sudo clamtk` or `sudo clamtk-gnome`

Comment: Thanks ThatGuy.  Just to clarify: on my laptop I run Lubuntu with an admin and a user account. I tried accessing Clam as user  via the terminal (as you suggested) and was told "This incident will be reported".  I was able to bring up the interface as admin both via the accessories menu and the terminal. However it does not appear to search for the updates and when asked to do a scan with the update it already has, it does a split second scan and reports no files were scanned.

Comment: I just looked in the clam log (/var/log/clamav and it said it couldn't find clamd.conf. I checked in etc/clamav and indeed this file is missing.  I'll find a copy of the file and see if that fixes things. It seems very strange that the file has vanished when it was there before for the first successful scan or two after I did the new install of Lubuntu.

Comment: Well, as I don't use clamd, decided not to do that.  Moving on and looking in freshclam.conf, I see it doesn't have the mirror address for my country to update the signatures. Unfortunately Lubuntu will not allow me to do anything to this file either as user or admin. Incidentally, Clam continues to do a fine job on my PC in Ubuntu 16.10.